# How to filter requests from only application context path?

Tags: jakarta-ee, filter, web.xml, url-mapping, java-ee-5

**Environment:**

- Jboss 5.2
- Servlet 2.4
- Java 7

I'm trying to execute a filter requests when the application context path is called but I didn't find any way with url-pattern.

I would like to execute a filter when request this url http://localhost:8080/myapp but the filter is not triggered.

```
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>PrincipalFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

I also tried with emtpy string but I got an error on parsing web.xml on deploying.

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried `<url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>`?

Comment: Yes, but this not only take context path but also all others. I was looking for only trigger for the context path.
Otherwise I could deal with the concrete path on doFilter method...